# Prove inequality $ab+bc+ca\ge 3,\ abc=1$

Tags: inequality

How can I prove
\begin{equation*}
ab+bc+ca\ge 3,~a,b,c \in\mathbb{R},~ a,b,c>0\ 
\end{equation*}
and the product $abc=1$?

I obtained only $(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge6\ and \ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+ab\ge 3$ with no further continuation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AM-GM inequality states that $x+y+z\geq 3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3}$ and is an extremely useful inequality to know.

By AM-GM inequality, we have $ab+bc+ca\geq 3(abc)^\frac{2}{3}$. However, since $abc=1$, the inequality follows.

Comment: thanks I will remember that

Answer (score 3):

You can use the harmonic-geometric inequality : the harmonic means of $a,b,c$ is defined by$$\frac1H=\frac 13\Bigl(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\Bigr)$$
and it is known that $H\le G$. Since $G=1$,
$$\frac1H=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\ge \frac1G=1.$$

Comment: very original thanks

Comment: In fact HM-GM is essentially the same inequality as AM-GM, but applied on the reciprocals.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it's good to know it *per se*, without having to reinvent the wheel each time one needs it.

Comment: Yup. (By the way I didn't insinuate that this answer is inferior or something; apologies if I seemed to.)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: AM-GM inequality ! Canyou see it??